# Trying to combine 3 fields and eliminate if it's the same

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to create a Sales report using crystal report 2013.
We have 3 fields within the same database which are Salesperson, Estimator 1 and Estimator 2.
I would like to combine those fields in the same column.  For example:  Salesperson: John Doe  Estimator 1: Sally Roe  Estimator 2: Jeremy Smith
We want to show those three people's name under the same column in different row only once (grouped).  Is this even possible in Crystal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can enlarge your Detail section and place the three fields under each other.

Then on the fields Estimator1 and Estimator2 write a suppress formula: (SalePerson = Estimator1) and (SalesPerson = Estimator2) respectively.

This will eliminate them upon duplication.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Zeina.  How do we grouped them?  we wanted each name to be grouped.

Comment: can you provide me with the structure of your data?